# Flutter Firebase how would I go about getting specific data from snapshot

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

I am currently using a realtime database for my application. I am having trouble reading specific user data from a snapshot.

My code:

```
  final databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference();

  void getData() {
    databaseReference.once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
      Map<dynamic, dynamic> values = snapshot.value;
      //print(snapshot.value['name']);
      print('Data : ${snapshot.value}');
    });
  }
```

My database layout:

```
Users:
     userId:
           name: TEST
           email: TESTEmail@gmail.com
           bio: TESTBio
```

I want to be able to read the name of an individual with a specific userId (for example Bdhsaiweuy2731319238121shda), how would I go about doing so? Thank you for your time, I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know their UID, you can look up that user directly with `databaseReference.child("Users/Bdhsaiweuy2731319238121shda")` and then read the data from there. Something like:

```
databaseReference.child("Users/Bdhsaiweuy2731319238121shda").once().then((DataSnapshot snapshot) {
  print(snapshot.value['name']);
});
```

Comment: This works bro beautiful, just need to change the databaseReference variable to look something more like this: databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child("users");

Answer (score 0):

`values` is a variable of type `map` and it will contain all the retrieved data. If you want access only to the `name` value, then you need to iterate inside this `map` and use the get `[]` operator to get the value of the `name`. Example:

```
values.forEach((key,values) {
      print(values["name"]);
      String name = values["names"];
    });
```

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.7.0/dart-core/Map-class.html